# Payment API for mobile App

Tags: magento2, api, payment-gateway, mobile, app

We are planning to develop native apps for magento2 website.Currently we're using **paytabs** as payment method no other options  for now. Here's [module](https://github.com/paytabscom/Paytabs-e-commerce-plugins/blob/master/Magento/paytabs-magneto-v2.3-express-checkout.zip) if you want to take a look.

Module it self using express checkout for payments. It just sending request to gateway with order details and in response rendering iframe.

How should I capture payment on apps by keeping magento between ?
Like, If we use SDK for accepting payments for mobile there would be more work for API to create invoice, sending notification etc.

That's reason we think to keep magento in between while accepting payment on mobile.

What is best way for payment integration for apps ? Any suggestion,ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find any best approach here?

Comment: Paytabs has rest API's at last I ended up using those still in progress hopefully customers can pay using cards on app :D

Answer (score 0):

A payment API (application programming interface) helps ecommerce [grocery app](https://www.softsuave.com/blog/guide-for-successful-grocery-delivery-app-development/) enterprises to manage payments in a seamless manner. Payment APIs have the potential to improve the payment process for both organisations and consumers, as they can speed up and secure transactions.